# Laravel Authentication Behaving Different for API Routes and Web Front End Routes

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, lumen

First of all, I'm new to PHP and Laravel so you have to forgive me for being a noob.

Anyway...

I've been following this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-api-only-jwt-powered-laravel-app/ to create an API in Laravel.

All the API calls work as expected. After following the tutorial, I decided I wanted a front-end views for login/register/forgotten password/reset password etc....

I noticed Laravel has the following command:

```
`php artisan make:auth`
```

This created the necessary files I need for the front end.

The issue I have is that `php artisan make:auth` seems to have made:

```
/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php
```

The tutorial I followed has these files for the API calls:

```
/app/Api/V1/Controllers/LoginController.php
/app/Api/V1/Controllers/ForgotPasswordController.php
/app/Api/V1/Controllers/SignUpController.php
/app/Api/V1/Controllers/ResetPasswordController.php
```

If I use the API or front end, they seem to act independently. For example if I register with the register front end, then use the front end or api to login, it fails with incorrect details. I assume its because the frontend uses `bcrypt` on the password to create the user. If I remove the `bcrypt` from the register front end, then use the front end to:
1. Register
2. Logout
3. Forgotten Password
4. Complete Reset Password
5. This logs me in, but if i logout and then try login, it no longer works.
Again I think this is due to the `bcrypt` of the front end ResetPasswordController.

My question is how can I get the front end and the api calls I have setup from the tutorial I followed to work the same way. It feels like I shouldn't have duplicated controllers in `/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/` and `/app/Api/V1/Controllers/` but I cant work out what to change.

I'd appreciate any help that can be provided.

Thanks

Comment: Different middlewares?

Comment: Not sure what that means... as I said I'm new to php and laravel... In the mean time I've removed the setPasswordAttribute function from my user model which was hashing the password. And then in the /app/Api/V1/Controllers/ for SignUpController and ResetPasswordController I set the password with bcrypt. Now the API calls work the same as the web front end. This doesn't feel correct though, but seems the best I can get it right now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you are using clean Laravel 5.3, then you have two routes, one for `web` calls and another for `api` calls. Both of them use their own middleware.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.